# GWT draggable CellTable cells

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop, gwt-celltable

I have a GWT CellTable - it's a pretty simple table with just a single string column.

What I'd like to do is drag rows of this table to a drop target (actually another table).  I've been trying to figure out how to attach a draggable event as described at ~23:00 of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEkR1ox_K10).

To which CellTable element can I set the draggable flag to TRUE.

I haven't gotten this far yet, but I'm sure I'll soon face a similar issue in setting the drop handler on the target table.

If someone could post an example or point me in the right direction, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Why the down vote?  I've explained what I'm trying to do and provided a link to the code I'm trying to emulate.  What else could I do to make the question better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at GwtQuery drag and drop plugin. It offers drag and drop support for CellWidget

Documentation : http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers

Example wit CellTable : http://gwtquery-plugins.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/droppable/demo/CellTableSample/CellTableSample.html